# Android Providing Styles Resources for Gingebread

Tags: java, android, themes, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am having some troubles to provide different styles resources for gingerbread or older versions of android.

I have defined 2 different style pages. the normal Styles and the Styles-v11.
For android 3.0 and UP works just fine, everything is OK. My problem is when I try on gingerbread it just ignores the style changes.

Styles:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <!--
       Styles for v1 to v10
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme"></style>

    <style name="Performance" parent="android:Theme"></style>

    <style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

    <style name="ColorsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>

    <style name="OsuTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

    <style name="BrazilTheme" parent="android:Theme"></style>

    <style name="NeonTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Styles-v11:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <!--
        Styles v11
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>

    <style name="Performance" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>

    <style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>

    <style name="ColorsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>

    <style name="OsuTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>

    <style name="BrazilTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>

    <style name="NeonTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

My app have a settings to check which theme is active.

```
switch (ThemesActivity.newTheme) {
    case ThemesActivity.THEME_DARK:
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dark);
        break;
    case ThemesActivity.THEME_LIGHT:
        setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_light);
        break;
    case ThemesActivity.THEME_COLORS:
        setTheme(R.style.ColorsTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_colors);
        break;
    case ThemesActivity.THEME_NEON:
        setTheme(R.style.NeonTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_neon);
        break;
    case ThemesActivity.THEME_PERF:
        setTheme(R.style.Performance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_performance);
        break;
    case ThemesActivity.THEME_OSU:
        setTheme(R.style.OsuTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_osu);
        break;
    case ThemesActivity.THEME_BRAZIL:
        setTheme(R.style.BrazilTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_brazil);
        break;
    default:
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dark);
        break;
    }
```

The problem is doesn't matter which theme is active in Gingerbread! ALWAYS loads the default app theme :(

I can't figure out what is going on wrong and why the theme change is not working for older versions.

Thank you very much.

edit:

I've tried also using:

```
 <style name="OsuTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"></style>
```

And still the same :( the theme doesn't change at run time, it only changes if I set the theme on the manifest.

On the manifest the themes work fines, the problem is when I try to change it during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

<style name="ColorsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>
```

The main problem is that Gingerbread just doesn't have style resources from themes that you extending. Thats why it load default resources.

Comment: But what would be the styles definition for the "Light" theme on gingerbread? I tried to find some info about that and failed, and on that part there is no hint from eclipse :(
I can use "Theme.Light" on the manifest and works as default theme for the app, but still don't recognize the theme change when I use it :(

Comment: I also got the library "HoloEverywhere" from https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere, but is SO CONFUSING! I have no idea what to with it o.O and the documentation is way too dificult to understand.